# $\int{(\sec^4{x})}dx = \cdots$

Tags: integration

I'm doing integration by substitution,

I've been asked to integrate $\int{\sec^4 x}dx$ using $ u = \tan{x}$. I did:
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \sec^2{x} \Rightarrow dx = \frac{du}{\sec^2{x}}\\.$$ Thus,
\begin{align}
\int{(sec^4{x})} dx& = \int{\left(\frac{sec^4{x}}{\sec^2{x}}\right)} du\\
& = \int{(\sec^2{x})}du\\
&=\int{(1+\tan^2{x})}du\\
&= \int{(1+u^2)}du\\
& = u + \frac{u^3}{3}+c\\
&= \tan{x} + \frac{\tan^3{x}}{3}+C.
\end{align}
However, the answer is actually:
$$\frac{\cos^3{x}}{3}-\cos{x}+c$$

It seems I'm close but have made a mistake, I don't understand.

Comment: Your answer is right, the book has a typo.

Comment: Wow, what a waste of time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, the solution in the book is wrong.  I've had this happen to me before and it's really frustrating.  When I was in integral calculus and I suspected this was happening this is how I would check. If you differentiate the answer they give you get:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\cos^3(x)}{3}-\cos(x)+C)=-\sin(x) \cos^2(x)+\sin(x).$$  Using $\cos^2(x)=\sin^2(x)-1$ we have,
$$-\sin(x)(1-\sin^2(x))+\sin(x)=\sin^3(x).$$  At this point you can be sure that $\sin^3(x)$ does not equal $\sec^4(x)$.  Since differentiation undoes integration you can be sure at this point their answer is wrong.

Comment: This is also a way to check your answer

Comment: I had no suspicion of the book being wrong, and assumed I was wrong. I probably should have tried differentiating though, to see whether the derivative was close to the original equation.